# Getting "exited with code=3221226356" error (STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION) while opening a output file stream

Tags: c++

As evolution of a school exercise I'm making a program that writes a file in every subfolder starting from the location where the program is executed.
So there is a recursive function and another function called inside that writes the file.

If I execute this I get "exited with code=3221226356" error the second time I'm writing the file (inside the first subfolder, when I create the ofstream)... **only while not in debug**. After a bit of experiments I removed the recursive call and the files into all the main directories are written. There are no arrays except the input variable (char*), what could be causing this memory leak?

This is the code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

const char * separator_char() {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        return "\\";
    #else
        return "/";
    #endif
}

void createCopy(const char * path) {
    const char * separator = separator_char();
    char * file_name_path = strdup(path);
    strcat(file_name_path, separator);
    printf("Writing Roberto.txt...\n");
    strcat(file_name_path, "Roberto.txt");
    std::ofstream dst(file_name_path, std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::trunc); -- ERROR HERE
    dst << "test";
    printf("Wrote %s\n", file_name_path);
    dst.close();
}

void multiply(const char * path) {
    const char * separator = separator_char();
    char * path_2 = strdup(path);
    strcat(path_2, separator);
    DIR * dir = opendir(path);
    struct dirent * entry = readdir(dir);
    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(entry -> d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry -> d_name, "..") && entry -> d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char * path_3 = strdup(path_2);
            strcat(path_3, entry -> d_name);
            printf("%s\n", path_3);
            createCopy(path_3);
            multiply(path_3);
        }
        entry = readdir(dir);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const char * PATH = ".";
    multiply(PATH);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(path_2, separator);` How many bytes do you expect `strdup` to add to `path_2`? Why would it add any extra space for you to concatenate?

Comment: "what could be causing this memory leak?" What memory leak? If you have a memory leak, you waste memoy but rarely cause any segmentation fault. That's basically the opposite of a memory leak. (which doesn't mean there aren't any leaks, but they don't cause your error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two lines are a likely problem:

```
char * file_name_path = strdup(path);
strcat(file_name_path, separator);
```

The `strdup` call allocates enough memory for the string you want to duplicate, not a single byte more.

That means the `strcat` call will cause your program to write pout of bounds of the allocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior* (and heap corruption).

One possible C-like solution is to use the [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function to construct your string. It can be used with a null pointer destination string and a zero size, then will return the number of bytes needed for the string (excluding the null-terminator). Then you can allocate memory for the string, and use `snprintf` again to actually create the string.

---

Or since you're programming C++, just use `std::string` and append as needed. No out-of-bounds problems, no memory leaks (which you also have).

And considering you're dealing with filesystem paths, use [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) instead:

```
void createCopy(std::filesystem::path const& path) {
    auto file_name_path = path / "Roberto.txt";
    std::ofstream dst(file_name_path, std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);
    dst << "test";
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!
I'm using std::string everywhere now, unfortunately I already tried with std::filesystem and it has some problems with the latest version of GCC, couldn't make it work... I gave up

Comment: @SidusBrist Earlier versions might need to link with the `stdc++fs` library (add the flag `-lstdc++fs` when linking). It was integrated into the normal C++ standard library with version 10 or 11. If you're using a later version and have problems, you might consider posting a question about it. :)